# Simplifying already defined symbols

Tags: programming

Consider the following code:

```
ClearAll[x, y]
x = y;
y = 2;
?x
?y
```

This will store $x$ being equal to *the variable $y$*, and $y$ having *the value of $2$*.

Now switch the assignment lines:

```
ClearAll[x, y]
y = 2;
x = y;
?x
?y
```

the internal representation will be $x=2$, $y=2$, since at the time of the assignment $x=y$, *the value of $y$* is known and used for the assignment, not the variable $y$ itself, as it has been in the first case.

Now consider the case where I've built up a long code with complicated expressions being substituted into each other, and at some final point I would like to boil this down as much as possible.

Stated differently: *How would I make sure $x$ is updated to the value of $y$ in the first example instead of still referring to $y$?*

Comment: these two pieces of code do get the the same result via a different route, if you want the second behavior use the second version. As you noted your self x=x will solve your "problem".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about defining this function

```
SetAttributes[updateSymbols, HoldAll]
updateSymbols[syms__] := 
   Scan[Function[x, If[ValueQ[x], x = x], HoldAll], Hold[syms]]
```

then running

```
updateSymbols[x, y]
```

after the definitions have been made?

It will redefine each symbol, evaluating the RHS of their definitions.

*Note:* Only works for `OwnValue`-symbols, and I'm not *entirely* sure it can't break something.

---

Usage example:

```
x=y;
y=2;

?x
(* ==>
 Global`x
 x=y
*)

?y
(* ==>
Global`y
y=2
*)

updateSymbols[x,y]

?x
(* ==>
Global`x
x=2
*)

?y
(* ==>
Global`y
y=2
*)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `SetDelayed` in place of `Set` in all assignments where you want your updating to happen:

```
x:=y
y:=2
...
```

Better still, use functions rather than variables and pass values locally, this will be cleaner.

*EDIT*

If you really want to "hard-code" to the final values, you either need to have a list of symbols you want, or get it somehow. Here is a possibility:

```
Cases[Names["Global`*"],
   name_ :> With[{heldSym = ToExpression[name, InputForm, HoldComplete]},
        Set @@ Join[heldSym, heldSym] /; OwnValues @@ heldSym =!= {}]]
```

This will "hard-code" all global symbols which have `OwnValues`, to their current values.

*EDIT 2*

Here is a local version of my code:

```
ClearAll[update];
SetAttributes[update, HoldAllComplete];
update[syms__Symbol] := Cases[Unevaluated[{syms}], s_ :> (s = s) /; OwnValues[s] =!= {}];
```

Comment: That won't solve the problem: `x:=y; y:=2` will not assign the value 2 to x once it is known. Of course, using `x` (in both my and your case) will print 2, but I'm looking to update the definition itself, as in "x will have ownvalue 2".

Comment: @David Ok, I see. Please see my edit. If you have an explicit list of symbols (perhaps, symbols wrapped in `Hold` or `HoldComplete`), this would be even easier.

Comment: Leonid, I fear I've asked this before, but why don't you use `MakeExpression[name]` in this kind of application?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard For no good reason, actually. You are right, it is a better fit here.

Answer (score 2):

As stupid as it sounds, `x = x` seems to work:

```
ClearAll[x, y]
x = y;
y = 2;

?x
?y
(* => x = y, y = 2 *)

x = x;
?x
(* => x = 2 *)
```

This basically evaluates `x`, and then assigns the result to `x` again. Written more explicitly, `x = x` is the same as `x = Evaluate[x]`.